# Problema al imprimir un dato en plantilla thymeleaf con Spring boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, thymeleaf

No consigo imprimir un String en una plantilla thymeleaf, que paso desde un controlador de Spring boot. Es un ejemplo muy básico. Al ejecutar el proyecto no parece haber ningún error.
Desde el único método del controlador paso un String para imprimir en dicha plantilla, pero esta no aparece impresa. Alguien puede arrojar algo de luz? gracias de antemano.

El archivo thymeleaf

```
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<body>
<p> texto de prueba </p>
<p th:text="${dato}"></p>
<p> otro texto de prueba </p>
</body>
</html>
```

Y el archivo del controlador de Spring boot

```
package com.jumpering.controller;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;

@Controller
public class ProductController{

    @RequestMapping("/")
    public String index(Model model) {

        model.addAttribute("dato", "mensaje aleatorio");
        return "index";
    }
}
```

Mediante `model.addAttribute("dato", "mensaje aleatorio");` paso la variable "dato", que se debería de imprimir en la plantilla thymeleaf.

Answer (score 1):

Tras dar vueltas, he descubierto que el problema estaba en la ubicación del archivo del 'main' de la aplicación:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Fijaros que el archivo 'main' está dentro del paquete 'com.example.demo'.
Aquí está el problema. Para que funcione, el archivo 'main' debe de estar en 'com.example'. No se porqué pasa esto, pero así me funciona el código.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Es en esta ubicación del archivo 'main', y aquí sí que funciona el código.